# magento homepage gives a blank screen

Tags: php, magento

I was working on my magento page  www.samsungtelefoonhoesjes.com and suddenly my homepage that normally works perfectly only shows everything until the home slider. after that everything is white....

The page worked 30 mins ago.

What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Can I use firebug or something for this where should I start?

- cleared cache
- reindexed
- removed cache
- disabled the slider (this was my last change i did)

Comment: Usually blank page is shown when missing a php ; closing or '. First take a look to the code after header.

Comment: Please share your cms page for that homepage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all The good information. My problem was the mega Menu banner . I deleted it from my page just before I changed my slider so I forgot about its . After returning the sample data the site is fixed again . Thanks for all the help .

Answer (score 0):

Firebug shows 500 Internal Server Error.

Try following solutions:

1. Check apache error_log, it should be in /var/log/apache2/error.log in most cases.
2. Check for permissions to your files and folders. Files should be 644 and folders should be 755. Reset permissions using [magento cleanup script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions).
3. Check your .htaccess file. 
   Check out this article. http://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting apache on the server, this worked for me.